# Can Jmol show an arbitrary number of molecules at once?

Tags: java, visualization, chemistry

I'm trying to display a group of dimers with Jmol, and can only seem to figure out how to display just one molecule at a time. Ideally, I would like to be able to load several molecules at once, and display each of them.

Is this actually possible with Jmol?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're talking about [this Jmol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jmol), then I'm inclined to believe that you'll have better luck tagging this question as [tag:java] instead of [tag:python]

Comment: Thanks! I'll tag that as well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is this relevant to Python, JavaScript and Java? Is this even about programming at all?

Comment: Technically Jmol is an application written in Java, but still uses Java commands in its terminal. So yes and no. I tagged python since I'm using python to feed data into Jmol. Hopefully this isn't too off topic for the site! I just haven't found much definitive information about Jmol's ability to show multiple molecules

Comment: There's tonnes of Jmol questions here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/ maybe try there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that website existed!